# Send All Post Data to Jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Is it possible to send all post data to PHP script via ajax? I know i could do:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'myurl/',
    data: {
       post1 : post_data_1
       post2 : post_data_2
       post3 : post_data_3
       ***
       ***
    }
  });
```

Is there a way of sending all Form data that has name attributes to php script without specifying each element using **data: { *** }**

Answer (score 6):

You can use `$('#FormID').serialize()`. It basically autogenerates your form data based on the names that you used in the HTML.

[Documentation is here.](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: will i be able to access it on php side using $_POST['name'] ?

Comment: indeed, that's what its for. Just make sure your name="whatever" matches the item you are receiving ($_POST['whatever']).